# How to use jquery with php if else conditions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a php condition like this:

```
<?php
    if($numResults > 0)
    { ?>
        <button id="unfollow" class="button"> unfollow </button>
<?php }

    else
    { ?>
        <button id="follow" class="button"> follow </button>
<?php } ?>
```

But in case the condition goes to "else statement", I want a jquery event handler so that when the user clicks on "follow" the button is faded out and the "unfollow" is faded in

I tried this but it only fades out the "follow" button and it doesnt fade in the "unfollow" button

```
$('#follow').click(function()
    {
        $("#follow").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#unfollow").fadeIn("slow");

    });
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, is the `unfollow` button ever written to the page?

Comment: Its only written if the condition goes to $numResults > 0

Comment: So how do you expect to fade the element in if it's not written to the page?

Comment: I know its wrong what im doing, that's why I need some help on what should I do.

Comment: In the else condition you need to create the unfollow button, but set it to display:none

Comment: You need to write both buttons to the page and hide the one you don't want to show at first.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Unfollow button -->
<button id="unfollow" 
        style="display:<?php echo ( $numResults > 0 ? 'none' : 'block' ); ?>"
        class="button">Unfollow</button>

<!-- Follow Button -->
<button id="follow" 
        style="display:<?php echo ( $numResults > 0 ? 'block' : 'none' ); ?>"
        class="button">Follow</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have them both on the page, with one initially faded out. Here it is working. http://jsfiddle.net/TzkGT/

```
<button id="follow" class="button"> follow </button>
<button id="unfollow" class="button" style="display: none;"> unfollow </button>


$('.button').click(function(){
    $("#follow").fadeToggle("slow");
    $("#unfollow").fadeToggle("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#follow').click(function()
{
    $("#follow").fadeOut("slow",function(){
    $("#follow").text("unfollow").fadeIn("slow");
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
    if($numResults > 0)
    { ?>
        <button id="unfollow" class="button"> unfollow </button>
<?php }

    else
    { ?>
        <button id="follow" class="button"> follow </button>
        <button id="unfollow" class="button"> unfollow </button>
        <style>
            #unfollow { display:none;}
        </style>
<?php } ?>
```

**Js**

```
$('#follow').click(function()
    {

        $("#follow").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#unfollow").css("display","block");
        $("#unfollow").fadeIn("slow"); // this may not require if you don't want effect

    });
```